# How to dynamically import `import x.y.z as z`in python

Tags: python, import, python-importlib

To do

```
import itertools
```

dynamically, I can do the following

```
import importlib
importlib.import_module('itertools')
```

But what should I do to do the following dynamically

```
import itertools as iters
```

**Problem Context:**

I need to import a different version (0.10) of a module('pika' in my case), installed in a separate directory instead of default version(0.9).

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Welcome to Python !!
>>> import importlib
>>> import pika
>>> pika.__version__
'0.9.14'
>>> import scale.lib.hypervisor.esx65.pika_3_5 as pika35
>>> pika35.__version__
'0.10.0'
>>> importlib.import_module('scale.lib.hypervisor.esx65.pika_3_5')
<module 'scale.lib.hypervisor.esx65.pika_3_5' from 'scale/lib/hypervisor/esx65/pika_3_5/__init__.pyc'>
```

As we can see regular imports are working fine. However when importing dynamically, importing relative to the location is causing issues. As per [importlib.import_module documentaion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) , following should work but it doesn't.

```
>>> importlib.import_module('pika_3_5', 'scale.lib.hypervisor.esx65')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named pika_3_5
```

And when trying to import 'pika' from a relative path, which should fail as there is no module pika under the relative path, it is still importing it from default module.

```
>>> importlib.import_module('pika', 'scale.lib.hypervisor.esx65.pika_3_5')
<module 'pika' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/__init__.pyc'>
>>>
```

What is it that I am missing ? I mainly want to do the following dynamically.

```
import scale.lib.hypervisor.esx65.pika_3_5 as pika
```

Comment: You've misunderstood what relative imports are. Neither `from whatever import thing` nor `import whatever.thing` are relative imports; relative imports are imports like `from . import thing`, where Python determines what to import based on what module the import occurs in. None of the stuff in importlib about relative imports is talking about your use case.

Comment: OK i got cause of error at least. I missed a '.' and it should be`importlib.import_module('.pika_3_5', 'scale.lib.hypervisor.esx65')` , .pika_3_5 and not just pika_3_5.

Comment: You seem to conflate loading a module with the name it is bound to in the current namespace. There are **two separate steps** when importing; loading the module if not yet loaded, and name binding. `importlib.import_module()` only covers the *first part*, and returns the loaded module object. How you then assign names in your current namespace from that module object is a separate step you didn't execute. `as alternative_name` influences the second part, and is outside the scope of the function.

Comment: Btw, why a negative vote on this question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To do
>
> ```
> import itertools
> ```
>
> dynamically, I can do the following
>
> ```
> import importlib
> importlib.import_module('itertools')
> ```

No, you do the following:

```
import importlib
itertools = importlib.import_module('itertools')
```

Similarly, to replicate `import itertools as iters`, you do

```
import importlib
iters = importlib.import_module('itertools')
```

`importlib.import_module` doesn't care what you call the module. `as` is not and cannot be part of `importlib.import_module`'s functionality. It just gives you the module object; what you call that object is up to you.

---

As for your context, you've misunderstood what a relative import is. The second argument to `importlib.import_module` has nothing to do with `from` imports, and `importlib.import_module('thing', 'whatever')` is not supposed to be equivalent to `from whatever import thing`.

If you want to do

```
import scale.lib.hypervisor.esx65.pika_3_5 as pika
```

that's `pika = importlib.import_module('scale.lib.hypervisor.esx65.pika_3_5')`. The second argument doesn't enter the picture. You seem to think this is somehow not dynamic, but it's as dynamic as any other importlib call.